# Kendo window restore is not calling resize event when minimized then restored

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

As per telerik documentation, Kendo window restore should call resize event. It works as documented when window is maximized & then restored. But, it's not calling resize event when window is minimized & then restored. I want to add some logic when window is minimized & then restored. Any idea how can I achieve this. Here is a sample kendo window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js">     </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog"></div>
<script>
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
                        width: "90%",
                        height: "90%",
                        title: "Lease Log",
                        position: { top: "5%", left: "5%" },
                        actions: [
                            "Pin",
                            "Minimize",
                            "Maximize",
                            "Close"
                        ],
                        resize: function(){
                            alert("resized")
                        },
                        restore: function(){
                            alert("restored")
                        },
                        maximize: function(){
                            alert("maximized")
                        },
                        minWidth: 500,
                        minHeight: 300
                    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per Telerik's [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events) they do not have a restore event.  The only thing I've been able to come up with is to add a mouse down event to the restore icon from the window's minimize and maximize events:

```js
                                $('.k-i-restore').on("mousedown", function (e) {
                                    console.log('restored');
                                });
```